# GoogleMaps URL string to display unique marker

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-markers

This is a topic I thought as easy as pie to solve with just a Google search and which is in fact quite complicated... When I use the following URL string to open a GoogleMaps window on a specific location, I get 2 markers (one green on the exact position of the Lat/Lng coordinates I put in the URL, and one red which is the nearbiest address) :

`https://maps.google.com/?q=46.9070919481631,0.243929350189987`

I would like to get just the green marker, whiwh means opening a new GoogleMaps window with a marker matching the Lat/Lng coordinates from the URL. This is quite simple, but I can't find out on the web if it possible or not...

Many many thanks for help !

Thomas

Comment: Using `near` instead of `q` you will get position of green marker. See also [an article about Google Maps' Parameters](http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I got on anoher stackexchange forum dedicated to GIS : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85997/googlemaps-url-string-to-display-unique-marker.